# When using unicode math, the math glyphs disappear

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math

Recently, I wanted to use unicode-math to introduce better distinguishable greek letters (e.g. boldface) at some point. However, I cannot seem to make things work. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % Must be loaded after amsmath.

%\setmathfont{Asana Math} % No matter what I select here
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$$
\alpha, \beta, \lambda
$$
\end{document}
```

No matter, which math font I choose, the greek letters are not shown and the log contains lines like:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6FC) in font "file:lmroman10-regular:sc
ript=latn;+trep;+tlig;"!
```

(ironically, my terminal does show the alpha). 
Why is the lookup being done in lmroman10-regular:sc (and how do I fix this)?

edit:
lualatex --version:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2016/dev) (rev 5238)
```

Filelist:

```
standalone.cls    2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone' cl
ass
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
unicode-math.sty    2015/09/09 v0.8b Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2015/09/11 v6002 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2015/09/11 v6002 L3 programming layer 
l3unicode-data.def    2015/07/20 v5676 L3 Unicode data
l3pdfmode.def    2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
ucharcat.sty    2015/08/23 v0.02 ucharcat for luaLaTeX (DPC)
  xparse.sty    2015/09/11 v6001 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2015/09/11 v6001 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
fontspec.sty    2015/07/22 v2.4d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
luaotfload.sty    2014/08/10 v2.5-4 OpenType layout system
luatexbase.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro progr
ammer
  luatex.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
    etex.sty    2015/09/02 v2.4 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
luatexbase-compat.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
luatexbase-modutils.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
luatexbase-loader.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
luatexbase-regs.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-attr.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-cctb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-mcb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2015/07/22 v2.4d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fontspec-luatex.sty    2015/07/22 v2.4d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
fontspec.cfg
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-luatex.sty    
lualatex-math.sty    2014/08/18 v1.4 Patches for mathematics typesetting with Lu
aLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
unicode-math-table.tex
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without the `varwidth` option, `standalone` typesets the document in a horizontal box and there `$$` just means an empty math formula. Thus `\alpha`, `\beta` and `\gamma` are being typeset in text mode. By a precise choice of the LuaTeX team, a math symbol in text mode *doesn't* raise an error and tries to typeset the (character corresponding to the) symbol in the current font.

In other words, you have discovered another good reason for never using `$$` in LaTeX. With `\[...\]` you get a different error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \]
```

Not really *very* helpful, but perhaps it could lead you to a real solution.

However, using `\[...\]` with the `varwidth` option will not give the wanted result.

Here's the right way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % Must be loaded after amsmath.

%\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\alpha, \beta, \lambda
$
\end{document}
```