# display-style math in a caption

Tags: math-mode, captions

I am trying to insert dispay-style math in the caption of a float, but I get an error.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
  \caption[short caption]{long caption with math
    \begin{equation*}
      1 \neq 0
    \end{equation*}
  }
  \label{tab:label}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & 3
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In this case I get

```
Missing $ inserted
```

or if I leave out the optional short version

```
Argument of \@caption has an extra }
```

I understand that the problem could be that the equation* environment is "fragile", and I need to protect it before using in the argument of a caption.
I haven't been able to do it. Is it possible to obtain this somehow?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if you replace `\begin{equation*}1 \neq 0 \end{equation*}` by `$1 \neq 0$` ?

Comment: More or less the same underlying issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334752/when-using-unicode-math-the-math-glyphs-disappear: you can't use display maths here as there is a box construct. `$\displaystyle ...$` should work

Comment: @JosephWright Indeed, using inline math and \displaystyle could be a possible workaround. But I would like to have it on a newline. I tried with \\, \newline or even with an empty line, but I always end up with the equation on the same line of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `\caption` first tries to fit the caption into one line by putting it into an `\hbox`.  Even if it doesn't fit, you will still get error messages from the attempt.  If you want to reduce the width of the caption, put it inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
  \caption[short caption]{
    long caption with math
    \begin{equation*}
      1 \neq 0
    \end{equation*}
  }
  \label{tab:label}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & 3
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, the problem was the check performed by `\caption` to fit the caption in a single line. `singlelinecheck=false` solves this.